# Should I mention calling conventions in pure virtual functions?

Tags: c++, windows, com, calling-convention

Here is an example, [IUnknown interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/unknwn/nn-unknwn-iunknown) from `Unknown.h` in Windows SDK:

- In C++:

```cpp
IUnknown {
    public:
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface( 
                REFIID riid,
                void** ppvObject) = 0;
        //AddRef
        //Release
};
```

- In C:

```c
typedef struct IUnknownVtbl {
    HRESULT (STDMETHODCALLTYPE *QueryInterface)(
        IUnknown* This,
        REFIID riid,
        void **ppvObject);
    //AddRef
    //Release
} IUnknownVtbl;

interface IUnknown {
    CONST_VTBL IUnknownVtbl* lpVtbl;
};
```

You can see `STDMETHODCALLTYPE` before the virtual functions which is `__stdcall` (generally). So, my question, is it important to mention calling conventions in pure virtual functions? Or calling conventions is managed internally in virtual functions by compiler or compiler options (e.g. `/Gz` for `__stdcall`)?

Also when I don't mention any calling conventions before virtual functions in source code (or with any compiler option), executable works fine.

Comment: A good reason for using the `STDMETHOD` macro family, which will do all this housekeeping for you.

Comment: And this is why Brian Harry hated COM and serendipitously invented the precursor to & foundations of .Net.

Comment: IUnknown is language-agnostic, so being explicit about the calling convention was quite important.  We can't tell what kind of client code is going to use your interface.  If it is guaranteed to be C++ code then thiscall is not wrong.

Comment: @Biswapriyo - how is pure virtual related to calling conventions ? this is independent things. anyway you always use some calling conventions on the any function. or implicitly via compiler option, or by default *thiscall* for member functions . or explicitly. when you declare api which used by different modules (so can be compiled with different calling conventions) need always explicit set api calling convention. in case member functions and if you use it only from *c++* modules - you can skip this (will be *thiscall*) but for use from another lang, in general need set to *__stdcall*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify them.  The fact that you are calling the function via (essentially) a function pointer makes no difference - the caller and the function called still need to agree on things like the order in which the parameters are passed.

But why do you *need* to specify them in the base class?

Well firstly I would expect the compiler to complain if you didn't, and secondly you might be calling said functions via an object or (more likely) pointer to an object of said base class, in which case the declarations in the base class are all the compiler has to go on.

Comment: This is a COM interface. At the ABI, composition isn't implemented as a class hierarchy, so talking about the base class strictly doesn't make sense. It is an implementation detail of how Visual Studio allows you to implement COM interfaces in C++.